# Why greater<int> and less<int> showing opposite behaviour?

Tags: c++, stl

Please consider following code,

```
using namespace std;
std::priority_queue<int,vector<int>,std::greater<int>> queue; //first

queue.push(26);
queue.push(12);
queue.push(22);
queue.push(25);

std::cout<<queue.top()<<endl;


std::priority_queue<int,vector<int>,std::less<int>> queue2; //second

queue2.push(26);
queue2.push(12);
queue2.push(22);
queue2.push(25);

std::cout<<queue2.top()<<endl;
```

> Output:
>
> 12
>
> 26

In first definition I used `greater<int>` still I am getting 12 (min value) as output, while when I use `less<int>` I get 26 (max value).

Shouldn't `greater<int>` create max heap?

Comment: the [docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) state clearly that if you use `std::greater` then the smallest values goes to the top

Comment: Maybe because `greater` and `less` are opposites?

Comment: Lack of research is a good bet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as the internal algorithm itself is concerned, `std::priority_queue` always creates "max heap". You just need to teach it to compare the elements in order for it know what's "max".

To determine the ordering for that "max heap", it uses a "less"-style comparison predicate: when given a pair `(a, b)` (in that specific order) the predicate should tell whether `a` is *less than* `b`. By using the ordering information obtained from the predicate `std::priority_queue` will make sure that the *greater* element is at the top of the heap. Standard `std::less` is an example of such predicate. Whatever predicate you supply, the implementation will treat it as a "less"-style predicate.

If you supply a predicate that implements the opposite comparison (like `std::greater`), you will naturally end up with minimum element at the top.  Basically, one can put it this way: `std::priority_queue` expects a "less" comparison predicate, and by supplying a "greater" comparison predicate instead you are essentially *deceiving* the queue (in a well-defined fashion). The primary consequence of that deceit is that for you (the external observer) "max heap" turns into a "min heap".

And this is exactly what you observe.

Answer (score 3):

Because that's their job. `less` and `greater` are supposed to model operators `<` and `>` respectively and are used by `priority_queue` to give order to its elements.

They yield opposite results because they're defined to do so (except for equal elements).

> Shouldn't `greater<int>` create max heap?

You're mistaking internal representation of the container with the interface of `top()` member function, which is supposed to yield the top element, as per the comparator.

Answer (score 2):

std::priority_queue is a "max heap". You provide a less-than operator; and the element at the top is the largest.

In your second example, you provided less-than to be the intuitive std::less; and you see the largest element at the top.

In your first example, you consider a larger int to be "less-than" a smaller int; and the "largest" element based your "less-than" is in fact the smallest int.